# Solutions with spherical symmetry of the wave equation in 3-dimensional space.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial t^2}= \nabla^2u$$

It is known that there are solutions with spherical symmetry of the form:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{v(r,t)}{r} ; r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
With $v(r,t)$ being a solution of the 1-dimensional wave equation in the coordinate $r$.

My question is, is there any solution **with spherical symmetry** of the 3-dimensional wave equation which is not of this form?

Answer (score 2):

No.  A solution $u(x,t)$ has spherical symmetry if and only if it can be written as
$w(r,t)$ for some function $w$.  This is  $v(r,t)/r$, where $v(r,t) = r w(r,t)$.  Substituting this function into the wave equation in $\mathbb R^3$, you get $$ \frac{1}{r}  \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} $$
so to be a solution, $v$ must satisfy the 1D wave equation.

Comment: Is there any proof or source for the implicit affirmation that such $w(r,t)$ must be of the form $w(r,t)=\frac{v(r,t)}{r}$?

Comment: Change to spherical coordinates.  There is no dependence on $\phi$ or $\theta$, so ...